# javacript logical "and" and logica "or"

Tags: javascript

I try to understand this code but I can't
code:

```
"i" != e &&  "I" != e || ( console.log("inc"),fw -= 10)
```

```js
console.log("------------------")
true && console.log("1 &&");
false || console.log("1 ||");

console.log("------------------")
false && console.log("2 &&");
true || console.log("2 ||");
```

example with "i"

```
// "i" != e &&
// "i" != e == false 
// the rest of the code should not be executed 

// "I" != e ||    
// "I" != e == true
// the rest of the code should not be executed 
"i" != e &&  "I" != e || ( console.log("inc"),fw -= 10)
```

but in both cases it is executed **( console.log("inc"),fw -= 10)** with **"i"** or **"I"**

my question is why is this behavior happening?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: If you google "javascript short circuit evaluation" you'll get a lot of good help.  The gist is that the end of a logical or need only be evaluated if the terms leading up to it are false.  For logical and, if the leading terms are all true.

Comment: my question is why is this behavior happening?

Comment: What else would you expect?

Comment: What is e here? `"i" != e`. Also, I guess what @VLAZ mean was that you have a couple of code pieces there. Do you understand only some of them or none of them? Which is the exact behaviour you are not able to undersand

Comment: This isn't great code.  Maybe you should rewrite it to more clearly express your intent.

Comment: You have EXP1 && EXP2 || EXP 3. If EXP1 is false, the EXP2 is not evaluated, because false && true/false remains false. Now you have false || EXP3, and the || (OR operator) need to evaluate the EXP3 to get the final result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works because `&&` is executed before `||`. That's not because of the operator order but because it has a higher precedence value. (For more info see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence))

So for example, assume that `e = "i"` and `fw = 0`:

1. `"i" != e &&  "I" != e || (console.log("inc"),fw -= 10)`
2. `false && <not evaluated> || (console.log("inc"),fw -= 10)`
3. `false || (console.log("inc"),fw -= 10)`
4. `false || -10`
5. `-10`

When `e = "I"` it goes like this:

1. `"i" != e &&  "I" != e || (console.log("inc"),fw -= 10)`
2. `true && false || (console.log("inc"),fw -= 10)`
3. `false || (console.log("inc"),fw -= 10)`
4. `false || -10`
5. `-10`

You could also write `("i" != e &&  "I" != e) || (console.log("inc"),fw -= 10)` to make it more clear but the result would stay the same.

Comment: thank you very much now if i understand :*

Answer (score 0):

And this is *also* an example of why **parentheses** are so important for clarity!  And, "why good ol' **if**-statements ought to be used.

The programmer in this case was either trying to be clever or was just being lazy.  The result was that his or her predecessor was so confused – by something that should have been written *clearly* – that he had to go to an online forum for help.

Please: "strive to make your source-code ***obvious."***  Such as this pseudocode

```
if (not ((e == "i") or (e == "I"))) {
   console.log("inc");
   fw -= 10;
}
```

That would have produced identical results just as quickly, but it would have been immediately apparent to anyone what it was intended to do.  The original code, although "shorter," cost time, frustration, and therefore money.  ***"Clarity"*** is a virtue.  Make your source-code "stupid simple." *Please.*

Comment: This seems like minified code. So, I doubt it was written by a human. At least I sincerely hope it wasn't.

Comment: I agree with what is said, but it does not answer the question.

Comment: I can't speak to that, VLAZ ... I honestly don't know.